# I am running a fresh c++ project with CMake but I get the following error

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

```
1> Provided 'inheritEnvironments' doesn't provide the necessary environment variables needed to set the context for the configuration x64-Debug. You can work around this by adding the necessary environment variables such as INCLUDE, LIBPATH, PATH and others to an environment block in your CMakeSettings.json.

1> CMake generation started for default configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Command line: "C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\PREVIEW\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\s107034\source\repos\CMakeProject1\out\install\x64-Debug"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2022\PREVIEW\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" "C:\Users\s107034\source\repos\CMakeProject1" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\s107034\source\repos\CMakeProject1\out\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is unknown
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:\Users\s107034\source\repos\CMakeProject1\CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
1> [CMake]   No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
1> [CMake]   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to
1> [CMake]   the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:\Users\s107034\source\repos\CMakeProject1\CMakeLists.txt:6 (project):
1> [CMake]   No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment
1> [CMake]   variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path
1> [CMake]   to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
1> [CMake] See also "C:/Users/s107034/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
1> [CMake] See also "C:/Users/s107034/source/repos/CMakeProject1/out/build/x64-Debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

The compiler cannot be found and I don't manage to make CMake find it. I have tried to put some specific bin locations in the PATH but don't manage to get it fixed. Moreover I have some colleagues who don't even have to mention a variable in the path to make the compiler be found.

The CMakeError file shows the following:

```
Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --c++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --ec++ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -Aa 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -D__CLASSIC_C__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: --target=arm-arm-none-eabi;-mcpu=cortex-m3 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified


Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" failed.
Compiler: CMAKE_C_COMPILER-NOTFOUND 
Build flags: 
Id flags: -c;-I__does_not_exist__ 

The output was:
The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: which compiler are you trying to use? If visual studio are you using a visual studio command prompt?

Comment: I am using visual studio indeed. I have a file that can be used as compiler normally: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.28.29333/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe

Comment: are you using a visual studio command prompt?

Comment: No, we use the open folder functionality of VS and then just compile using the IDE.

Comment: VS 2022 is a beta, have you tried using a release version of VS?

Comment: I started with VS 2019, where I had the same problem. Reinstalling VS doesn't help.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the suggestion of the error message and set C and C++ compilers in either `CC` and `CXX` environment variables or in `CMAKE_C_COMPILER` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` CMake variables?

Comment: Yes I did but it does not recognize the file as the correct compiler.  What file should I exactly refer to as CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER?

Comment: Compiling in the correct Visual Studio Command prompt could fix the detection.

Comment: How should I do this? By running vcvarsall.bat?

Comment: I have the same issue if open cmake project with msvs2019. Did you find any solution?

Comment: Please check [this issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/cmakesettingsjson-inheritenvironments-stopped-work/1321110) in the Microsoft Developer Community support forum. Also check [this other issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CMake-error-No-CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-could/10285815) I recently opened to bring up the problem again